# example to build groovy json and with groovy builder needed

Tags: json, groovy

```
empData1.groovy
def empMap[] =
       [1:2,
           2:2,
       3:[1:2,3:3,4:890,A:B],  //Map inside Map
       4:4,
       6:7
      ]


empData2.groovy
def empMap1[] =
       [91:21,
           92:22,
       93:[81:82,83:3,84:890,A:B], ////Map inside Map
       94:4,
       96:7
      ]
```

emp3.groovy
 -
 - Q1: how can i build a builder for like empMap/empMap1 
    - Q2: if i  want to do in emp3.grrovy like 
   empData1.include(empMap1) map data    copies to map2

is the same thing is achievavle vis groovy json how ?

is this possible to do

```
def json = new JsonBuilder()
 def result = json {
      1  2              //build a map with 1 as key 2 value without sinlge quaote is this possible
      3  33             //build a map with 3 as key 33 value without sinlge quaote is this possible
 }
```

println  result

```
**Answer
def json = new JsonBuilder()
 def result = json {
      '1'    '2'              
      '3'    '33'             
 }

println  result
```

My output    **[1:2, 3:33]**

**but i try to build something like this**

```
def json = new JsonBuilder()
 def result = json {
      '1'    '2'              
      '3'    '33'             
      '4'   (
          '1'   '3'
          '4'   '5'
      )
 }

println  result
```

**it gives me compilation error any clue to resolve it**

Comment: So you get the message that the title of this question is the same as that of a previous question (which was also yours) and the *best* you can think of is append a number? You *should* have chosen a more meaningful title instead.

Comment: Why not just use [JsonBuilder](http://groovy.codehaus.org/gapi/groovy/json/JsonBuilder.html).  I struggle to make sense of this question though, so I'm probably missing the point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anish, I suggest you try this instead to make it compile:

```
import groovy.json.JsonBuilder

def json = new JsonBuilder()
def result = json {
  '1'    '2'              
  '3'    '33'             
  '4'   {
      '1'   '3'
      '4'   '5'
  }
}
println  json
```